# Show input name in the second page forwarded form

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, session

I have two form. I want to show `mobile` in the second from where mobile will come through session. Here session id is showing but `mobile` is not showing.

1st form / page: sign.php

```
<?php session_start();
<?php $r=session_id();?>
<?php include('include/config.php');?>
<form class="ff" action="signc.php" method="POST">
<a>Enter Your Mobile No.</a>
<input type="text" id="inp" name="mobile" required>
</br></br>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="continue">
</form>
```

signc.php

```
<?php session_start();
<?php $r=session_id();?>
<?php include('include/config.php');?>
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `mobile_message`  SET `mobile` = '$mobile'");

 if($sql){

    $_SESSION['s']= "OTP sent to your mobile.";
        header('Location:sign2.php');

} else{
    $_SESSION['e']=  "Could not able to execute. ";
    header('Location:sign.php');

}
```

2nd form / page: sign2.php

```
<?php session_start();
<?php $r=session_id();?>
<?php include('include/config.php');?>
<form class="ff" action="sign2c.php" method="POST">
<a class="ase" >Enter Your Mobile No.</a>
<?php
    $cid=$_SESSION['cid'];
    $_q=mysqli_query($connection, "select * from mobile_message where mobile='$cid'");
    $_t=mysqli_fetch_array($_q);
    echo $_t['mobile'];
    echo $r;
    ?>
</br></br>
<a class="ase" >Enter Password</a>
<input type="text" id="inp" name="otp" required>
</br>
<input type="submit" id="btn" value="continue">
</form>

<!--hgfh-->
```

`echo $_t['mobile'];` shows nothing

`echo $r;` shows  `cgvk2tla6r14h38i2v7dlhkj80`

Comment: you assigned session value to $r **<?php $r=session_id();?>** thats why it shows **echo $r;  >> shows  `cgvk2tla6r14h38i2v7dlhkj80`**

Also try set id=mobile.  not name-mobile

Comment: remove session_start() from signc.php,sign2.php

Comment: in signc.php file you haven't retrieve mobile in $mobile variable

Comment: @kranthi when I remove session_start() from signc.php, sign2.php then nothing shows. How will I get mobile in the sign2.php page?

Comment: @Abhishek how to retrieve mobile in $mobile variable in signc.php file

Comment: @Vishwa how to set set id=mobile?

Comment: $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

Comment: <input type="text" id="mobile" name="mobile" required>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add these two lines in `signc.php`

```
$cid=$_POST['mobile'];

$_SESSION['cid']=$cid;
```

Corrected `signc.php` will be like

```
<?php session_start();
<?php $r=session_id();?>
<?php include('include/config.php');?>
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO `mobile_message`  SET `mobile` = '$mobile'");

 if($sql){

    $cid=$_POST['mobile'];

    $_SESSION['cid']=$cid;

$_SESSION['s']= "OTP sent to your mobile.";
    header('Location:sign2.php');

} else{
$_SESSION['e']=  "Could not able to execute. ";
header('Location:sign.php');

}
```